# Создание SVG карты в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, map

Практически везде рассматривается добавление именно готовых карт Google Maps. Что делать если нужно добавить в приложение свою, кастомную SVG карту. Из функционала достаточно зума и кликабкльных меток.

Comment: Что делать - углубляться в вопрос и писать самому или поискать (возможно доделать) готовые "сторонние" библиотеки

Comment: @woesss Единственная сторонняя библиотека, которую я нашел - SVGMapView больше не поддерживается. Я надеялся что за несколько лет появились новые сторонние или встроенные решения.

Comment: Ну а что мешает **вам** её "поддержать" - кто же будет это делать, если все будут ждать готовое-халявное? Библиотеки так и живут - их создают/поддерживают для нужд проекта. Если она становится популярной и собирает донаты, либо разработчик видит в ней такую перспективу - тогда уже ей занимаются целенаправленно